# How to pass parameters from Watson Assistant into a cloud function deployed on IBM Cloud

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

**What I am trying to achieve**:
Pass parameters into a cloud function deployed on IBM Cloud.

**What I have tried**:
Below are the parameters I save in the Watson Assistant node and trying to pass to the IBM cloud function.

```
"parameters": {
"startTime": "$startTime",
"locationName": "$locationName"
},
```

Below are codes I used to connect to my IBM cloud function:

```
{
  "context": {
    "private": {
      "my_credentials": {
        "user": "{*//user_id}",
        "password": "{*//password}"
      }
    },
    "startTime": "@sys-date",
    "locationName": "@TaiwanArea"
  },
  "output": {
    "generic": []
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "/itouristworld_dev/itouristweather/weather",
      "type": "cloud_function",
      "parameters": {
        "locationName": "$locationName"
      },
      "credentials": "$private.my_credentials",
      "result_variable": "result"
    }
  ]
```

So I thought the parameters $startTime and $locationName should be passed to IBM cloud function.

Then on my IBM cloud function, I use these codes:

```
var request = require("request-promise");

function main(params) {
   var options = {
      url: "https://opendata.cwb.gov.tw/api/v1/rest/datastore/F-C0032-001?format=json",
      headers: {
          Authorization: "{key}"
      },
      qs: {        
        locationName: `${params.locationName}`
      },
      json: true,
      encoding: "utf-8"
   };

   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      request(options, function (err, resp) {
         if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return reject({err: err});
         }
      return resolve({response: resp.body});
      });
   });
}
```

The response give me the whole packges of JSON data.
For example, If I would like to ask Watson Assistant" what's the weather in Taipei today?" 
it gives me all Taiwan condition instead of Taipei area which I should store "Taipei" as  $locationName.

**What I observed**
I test the parameters with "新北市"(name of the area) and param.loactionName in IBM cloud function. It gives me the following responses :

【parameters-->"新北市"】It gives me the right area match up with the parameters.

```
啟動 ID：
4aa67d030b8d45b6a67d030b8db5b6c4
結果：
{
  "response": {
    "records": {
      "datasetDescription": "三十六小時天氣預報",
      "location": [
        {
          "locationName": "新北市",
          "weatherElement": [
            {
              "elementName": "Wx",
              "time": [
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-18 06:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "多雲",
                    "parameterValue": "4"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-17 18:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-18 18:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "多雲",
                    "parameterValue": "4"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-18 06:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-19 06:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "多雲",
                    "parameterValue": "4"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-18 18:00:00"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "elementName": "PoP",
              "time": [
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-18 06:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "20",
                    "parameterUnit": "百分比"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-17 18:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-18 18:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "10",
                    "parameterUnit": "百分比"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-18 06:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-19 06:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "10",
                    "parameterUnit": "百分比"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-18 18:00:00"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "elementName": "MinT",
              "time": [
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-18 06:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "25",
                    "parameterUnit": "C"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-17 18:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-18 18:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "25",
                    "parameterUnit": "C"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-18 06:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-19 06:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "24",
                    "parameterUnit": "C"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-18 18:00:00"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "elementName": "CI",
              "time": [
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-18 06:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "舒適"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-17 18:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-18 18:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "舒適至悶熱"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-18 06:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-19 06:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "舒適至悶熱"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-18 18:00:00"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "elementName": "MaxT",
              "time": [
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-18 06:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "26",
                    "parameterUnit": "C"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-17 18:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-18 18:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "32",
                    "parameterUnit": "C"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-18 06:00:00"
                },
                {
                  "endTime": "2019-05-19 06:00:00",
                  "parameter": {
                    "parameterName": "29",
                    "parameterUnit": "C"
                  },
                  "startTime": "2019-05-18 18:00:00"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "result": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "datasetDescription",
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "id": "locationName",
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "id": "parameterName",
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "id": "parameterValue",
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "id": "parameterUnit",
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "id": "startTime",
          "type": "Timestamp"
        },
        {
          "id": "endTime",
          "type": "Timestamp"
        }
      ],
      "resource_id": "F-C0032-001"
    },
    "success": "true"
  }
}
日誌：
[]
```

【parameters-->params.locationName】It gives me location[], then I back to Watson Assistant check the dialogue, even though I type "新北市" as the keyword, I still get location[] as feedback.

```
啟動 ID：
6e18ca5d4dfe457198ca5d4dfe45712c
結果：
{
  "response": {
    "records": {
      "datasetDescription": "三十六小時天氣預報",
      "location": []
    },
    "result": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": "datasetDescription",
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "id": "locationName",
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "id": "parameterName",
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "id": "parameterValue",
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "id": "parameterUnit",
          "type": "String"
        },
        {
          "id": "startTime",
          "type": "Timestamp"
        },
        {
          "id": "endTime",
          "type": "Timestamp"
        }
      ],
      "resource_id": "F-C0032-001"
    },
    "success": "true"
  }
}
日誌：
[]
```

Comment: Your question is a bit muddled. You need to rework the question so that it makes sense, and give potential responders a chance to help you out. Start with the basics - what are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? What is the code you are showing? How do you expect it to work? What functionality are you actually observing? Based on what you have written, I am about 25% confident that you are trying to pass parameters into a cloud function deployed on IBM Cloud, but that is really just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Sorry for my poor English and I just learn how to code, so I don't know how to express my question correctly.
I modify my question make it more specific, hopefully, it could show you what's my question.

Comment: For your simple function, what does the Cloud Function activation log show?

Comment: Hi data_henrik, thanks for your reply, I change the codes a little bit. Please take a reference and see if you know where I did wrong, thank you for your patience and kindly help.